# Howto setup POJO validation in reactive micronaut

Tags: micronaut

With micronaut.io, how do I setup POJO validation of reactive HTTP body content?
It works for the syncronous case, ie:

```
@Post("/sync/{id}")
HttpResponse createSync(String id, @Body @Valid SomePojo pojo) {
    ...
}
```

but it doesn't work in the async case:

```
@Post("/async/{id}")
Single<HttpResponse> createAsync(String id, @Body @Valid Single<SomePojo> pojoProducer) {
    ...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please file an issue. Maybe we can do something about it

Comment: Thanks, https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/769

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I have found is to declare a method in the controller that triggers validation and use it this way:

```
    pojoProducer
        .map(pojo -> validate(pojo))
        ...

public <T> T validate(@Valid T t) {
    return t;
}
```

but it would be nice if the framework could do it for me..